# How to include support for all page types, calendar urls, archive, etc

Tags: php, urls, calendar

I'm writing a plugin and I get this error when viewing calendar urls for example the calendar archive list on a wordpress site. I do not get the error on posts or pages, only get error when viewing a set of posts via calendar/archive/calendar url (example of what I mean by calendar url. thewebsite.com/2021/08 -not an actual link-.). (Also, the error shows on the search page.) I assume the error means I am not including compatibility for other types of pages, like archives, searches, urls showing sets by date, etc. I'm new to programming. Please give me any comments if you have any thoughts after seeing this portion of code. The error message is **"Notice: Trying to get property 'post_type' of non-object"** The code I am trying to write better:

```
$wp_the_query   = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
$queried_object = $wp_the_query->get_queried_object();
$post_object    = sanitize_post( $queried_object );
$post_type      = $post_object->post_type;
$post_id        = $post_object->ID;
```

UPDATE:
Below is the way I solved the problem, changed the code to this:
(please comment if you see problems.)

```
$wp_the_query   = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
$queried_object = $wp_the_query->get_queried_object();

if ( is_singular() ) :
 $post_object    = sanitize_post( $queried_object );
 $post_type      = $post_object->post_type;
 $post_id        = $post_object->ID;
endif;
```

Comment: Not all queries have a queries object. So after using get_queried_object() you need to check if a value was returned.

Comment: I don't understand how to do that exactly. But I will tell you all the visual aspects are correct in the page. But the error shows. So I assume you mean I need to make the function skip only part of the function. Correct?

Comment: Right, just check `if ( $post_object )` before doing anything with it.

Comment: Thanks. That gave me ideas and I think I solve the problem. See the edited original if you want to see what I wrote to solve the issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add a check if the view that you are currently on is a single-view page or an archive ( or any other taxonomy page ). If you are on an archive page, the `get_queried_object()` will not return a Post object, therefore the error

The check you need to add can be the following:

```
if ( ! is_archive() ) {
    $wp_the_query   = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
    $queried_object = $wp_the_query->get_queried_object();
    $post_object    = sanitize_post( $queried_object );
    $post_type      = $post_object->post_type;
    $post_id        = $post_object->ID;
}
```

Comment: Good idea but if I understand correctly that would be a "if its not archive" then don't do that part of the function. Yes yes I know that. But this will not work in this case. Because I don't know how to write the second part to add support for the other pages. That was my original question.

Comment: `is_archive()` is true for data archives, which don't have a queried object, so this wouldn't solve the error.

Comment: Thanks. That helped. I edited the original to show what I did to make it function well.